# What kind of project do I need to create?

Tags: web-services, azure, project

I need to create a .net based Restful web service to interface to an existing SOAP back end application, This web service will be deployed to Azure. Using Visual Studio 2015, what kind of project do I need to create? Could your answer cover in some detail the steps I need to create this project?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use C#. [Here's a pretty good tutorial by Microsoft that covers all the steps of creating a basic web interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302124%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

I recommend you do the whole walkthrough, even if it doesn't immediately solve your issue, it will teach you how to do it.